# Why would people have a problem with singing above C4 (or C5 if female)?

Tags: voice

An organist told me that people often complain that singing above C4 (or c5 if female) is too high.
Why would people have a problem with singing above C4 C5 if female)?

Comment: Are those complainers male or female? Did those complainers lose their voice at some point (like my mother reports had happen to her)?

Comment: Middle C is generally accepted as C4. So C3 is an octave *lower*.

Comment: What does "Did those complainers lose their voice at some point" refer to?

Comment: Sounds like either a. Organist has a different perception of C4/5, or b. Organist is talking rubbish!

Comment: @Tim - if you spent a lot of time with Yamaha gear you might consider C3 to be Middle C. I'd ask the organist for clarification.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I think Yamaha is out there on its own. Virtually every other manufacturer calls middle C C4.

Comment: @ Dekkadeci, they are male and female.

Comment: @Hank - Oops, I mean "lost their singing voice". My mother says that she used to have a great singing voice when she was young, but she implies that now both its range and quite possibly its timbre are substantially worse than they used to be. I don't think she's alone in this world.

Comment: Did she quit singing at a certain age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 
a) adult always sing too low with children when singing baby songs - also primary school teachers and church song books are making compromises to the breast voice.

b) pop songs are always in  a range too low, girls are singing in a tenor range and boys are transposing an 8va down. Then the kids  have fear and hesitation from singing high.

The point is that they don't use the head resonance, they are fixed in the breast resonance.

I know this problem very well as I had always pupils arguing and complaining like that. They can be helped very easy by singing the tunes first on vowels like i, ü, u, ooh, then opener vowels like ö, ou, oo, e, a. You must work a lot with imagination and imitation animal cries like a horse, a cock, an donkey. Old Mac Donald had a farm is very useful for this.

This teacher tells exactly my experience:

We had a  national federal president who said (in political and economical concerns):

**the upswing begins in the head**

That's exactly the right answer - also for singers!

**Eidt:**

I actually have to add this Amee Nolte video:

So learn to sing with your head-voice!